# Ubuntu 20.10 is not GDPR compliant

Tags: 20.10, legal

I've just get an Ubuntu 20.10 and when launching the Agenda application I can see the meteo for 3 days. But those data came from a tier provider that I did not aware about. To give me my place meteo it know at least where I stay and my IP address and ...
At installation time it did not ask me to accept any tier provider ...

It seems that Ubuntu 20.10 is not GDPR compliant.

Comment: If this is important to you, it would be prudent to [file a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) and follow it through to ensure the development team behind the Agenda application are able to bring it into compliance. Reporting it here will not accomplish much, as many of the people on this site are neither Canonical employees nor developers 

Comment: Besides Matigo's suggestion:  If you have  questions about data gathering you can also use: https://ubuntu.com/legal/data-privacy#your-right-to-complain

Comment: On this subject: https://ubuntu.com/blog/tag/gdpr  https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-security-compliance  and an example of a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/base-files/+bug/1867424

Comment: So what you're saying is that this "Agenda" application, whatever that is, is not GDPR-compliant. Not Ubuntu itself.

Comment: Thanks @muru, but I think from the user's perspective, when only install a fresh Ubuntu OS, it's a Ubuntu concern. Tier services acceptance may be ask at first time run.

Comment: In any case, the place to discuss that is Launchpad by filing bug report.

Comment: thanks @Rinzwind, I'll follow your tips ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bug reported [1912616](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/agenda.app/+bug/1912616) for agenda.app with GDPR tag